# how to add ellipsis if the teaser is trimmed?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How?

I have the length set up to 600 chacters in the `manage diplsay`,

but then it just chops the content off,

and it's not at all obvious that there IS a continuation sometimes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another module called 'Smart Trim' which quite worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [Field Ellipsis](http://drupal.org/project/field_ellipsis) module will add a field formatter that does what you want.